# Checking a range of checkboxes between 2 boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a table of rows, each row has a checkbox. I have built a function that detects if the shift key had been pressed then, if it has then once 2 checkboxes are checked it will check the boxes between them.

The function works to some degree, however for some reason I have to check a third box to tick the boxes in-between.

How do I alter the code so it checks the boxes on the second check and not have to check a third?

Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

Vue Data:

```
data: () => ({
  keycheck: false,
  checkRows: []
})
```

Created:

```js
created() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
      this.keycheck = true
      console.log('The shift key is being held down...')
    }
  })

  window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
      console.log('Upper')
      this.keycheck = false
      this.checkRows = []
      //console.clear();
    }
  })
},
methods: {
  checkbox(key) {
    if (this.keycheck) {
      this.checkRows.push(key)

      if (this.checkRows.length === 2) {
        console.log(this.checkRows)

        for (let i = this.checkRows[0]; i <= this.checkRows[1]; i++) {
          let bData = this.displayed_array

          bData[i]['rowCheck'] = true
          console.log('test')
        }
      }
    }
  },
},
```

Comment: How are you binding the value to the checkbox and triggering `checkbox()`?

Comment: <input
                      v-model="order.rowCheck"
                      class="checkContainer"
                      type="checkbox"
                      @click="checkbox(key)"
                    />

Comment: Thanks as in the example above using the click on the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this out. By adding `this.$forceUpdate()` it updates the data. This was previously done by the third click.

```
methods: {
  checkbox(key) {
    if (this.keycheck) {
      this.checkRows.push(key)

      if (this.checkRows.length === 2) {
        console.log(this.checkRows)

        for (let i = this.checkRows[0]; i <= this.checkRows[1]; i++) {
          let bData = this.displayed_array

          bData[i]['rowCheck'] = true
          console.log('test')
         this.$forceUpdate()
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. However, right now if you're not holding shift, the first click is not registered in the `checkRows` variable. So you have to hold shift on the first click for it to work in two clicks.

```
if (this.keycheck) {
    this.checkRows.push(key);
```

I replicated it in this codepen: https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/pozbadW

FYI it's also better to set the array to empty using `this.checkRows.length = 0;` because it doesn't make a copy of the array.

Comment: Thanks... However in your example I have to select a box first, then unselect it then I can hold shift and select multiple... Any ideas?

Comment: Don't worry! Just figured it out. Added: this.$forceUpdate(); I'll add an answer! Thanks